# Calculation of logarithm in awk

Tags: awk

How to compute a logarithm with base 10 in awk?
I tried

```
-2.5*log(10)($2)/log(10)
```

The output: 83051.02180161216529 gave  -5.7564, but it should be -12.29836. Thank you.

Comment: You shouldn't have the first `(10)`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The proper formula for logarithm on base 10 is:

```
log($2)/log(10)
```

and it give the correct answer:

```
echo 83051.02180161216529 |awk '{print 2.5*log($1)/log(10)}'
12.2984
```

Comment: @Sulthan, on any base, not only `e` :)

Answer (score 3):

`log` is for base e (natural logarithm).  Just change it to

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{print -2.5*log(83051)/log(10)}'

-12.2984
```

the scaling will convert to base 10.