# Is there a way to summarize second fields for single identifiers using awk and replace output with nonnumbers?

Tags: shell, awk, delimiter

I have a **.txt** file:

```
a 10
b 13
a 2
b 5
c 1
```

Where  the first column is for the identifiers, and the second one is for the values.

If I wanted to go over the file using awk and sum up the numbers in the second column for each item in the first column, then replace it with * before printing so the output is as below, how would I go about that?

```
a : **
b : **
c : *
```

So that the number of stars is equal to the number of digits in the number (12 -> **, 18 -> **, 1 -> *)

```
awk '{gsub("12", "**"); print}' test.txt
```

I've tried this, but of course it's not the right solution. Open for any advice.

Comment: The number of stars is 1 + the integer part of the log base 10 of the number.  This link shows log10:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/54523885/1216776

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You may use this awk:

```sh
awk '{sums[$1] += $2} END {for (i in sums) {
gsub(/./, "*", sums[i]); print i, ":", sums[i]}}' file

a : **
b : **
c : *
```

Answer (score 5):

Could you please try following, written and tested with shown samples.

```
awk '
FNR==NR{
  arr[$1]+=$2
  next
}
($1 in arr){
  gsub(/./, "*", arr[$1])
  print $1, ":", arr[$1]
  delete arr[$1]
}
' Input_file Input_file
```

Answer (score 2):

To get the digit length of a number call `length` on it, e.g.:

```
print length(12)
```

Output:

```
2
```

Here is an example that works with GNU awk using printf's variable width and precision pattern (`%*s`):

*parse.awk*

```
{ h[$1] += $2 }
END {
  for (k in h) {
    padding = sprintf("%*s", length(h[k]), "")
    gsub(/ /, "*", padding)
    print k " : " padding
  }
}
```

Run it like this:

```
awk -f parse.awk infile
```

Output:

```
a : **
b : **
c : *
```